# comparing data from two different mysql tables insert new data and update the data that don't match

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to compare data from different tables, insert new data, and update the data that don't match.

Example:

```
I have table1 
------------------------------------
| ITEMNO | DESCRIPTION  |  FORSALE |
------------------------------------
| 123456 | Description1 |   YES    |
------------------------------------
| 234567 | Description2 |   YES    |
------------------------------------
| 345678 | Description3 |   YES    |
------------------------------------
```

and i also have table2 which is only a temporary table

```
----------
| ITEMNO |
----------
| 123456 |
----------
| 234567 |
----------
```

ITEMNO is Primary Key in table1 and Foreign Key in Table2

So, when a module from the program is sending data and it will firstly check the table2 and then compare the data with table 1

if the the sent data is like this

```
  table2        table1
----------    ----------
| ITEMNO |    | ITEMNO |
----------    ----------
| 123456 |  = | 123456 | (MATCH WITH TABLE1 AND TABLE2 THEN UPDATE)  
----------    ----------
| 234567 |  = | 234567 | (MATCH WITH TABLE1 AND TABLE2 THEN UPDATE)
----------    ----------
| 567890 |  = | 567890 | (NEW DATA THEN INSERT INTO TABLE 1)
----------    ----------
              | 345678 | (DOESN'T EXIST IN TABLE2 BUT EXISTS IN TABLE 1 SO UPDATE FORSALE FIELD TO "NO")
              ----------
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, it's can't be done with pure sql since mysql doesn't support `MERGE` statement like oracle. You need branching in php to solve this.

Comment: @RubahMalam oh gosh, pardon me. i forgot to that i also use php as the programming language.

Comment: is there any insert form??

Comment: @Abdulla it is a web service, so, no. sorry.

Comment: so then how you add data to temporary table is there any variable associate with it??

Comment: @Abdulla it is on different module which basically only a back up from table1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by below 2 sql-

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.itemno=t2.itemno 
SET t1.FORSALE='No' 
WHERE t2.itemno IS NULL;

INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 (itemno) SELECT t1.itemno 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.itemno=t2.itemno 
WHERE t2.itemno IS NULL;
```

But better option will be use of stored procedure, which will first get un-matched itemno from below query and keep it in a cursor then update and insert based on primary key as by it you can avoid locking-

```
SELECT t1.itemno 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.itemno=t2.itemno 
WHERE t2.itemno IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, will try it and i will update anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 Queries. You might try this :

```
//NEW DATA THEN INSERT INTO TABLE 1
insert into table1(item_no,description)
select item_no,description
from table2
where item_no not in(
    select item_no from table1
);
```

and

```
//DOESN'T EXIST IN TABLE2 BUT EXISTS IN TABLE 1 SO UPDATE FORSALE FIELD TO "NO"
update table1
set forsale = 'NO'
where item_no not in(
    select item_no from table2
)
```

and no action if `TABLE1 AND TABLE2` matched.